# Wordpress - Send email to users when they get new followers

Tags: php, wordpress, email, author

I'm using a simple plugin "[user following system](https://pippinsplugins.com/series/creating-a-user-follow-system-plugin/)" And all what i need to do is sending an email after the users get a new followers.

I think this is the important part of the plugin code:

```
function pwuf_follow_user( $user_id, $user_to_follow ) {

    $following = pwuf_get_following( $user_id );

    if ( $following && is_array( $following ) ) {
        $following[] = $user_to_follow;
    } else {
        $following = array();
        $following[] = $user_to_follow;
    }

    // retrieve the IDs of all users who are following $user_to_follow
    $followers = pwuf_get_followers( $user_to_follow );

    if ( $followers && is_array( $followers ) ) {
        $followers[] = $user_id;
    } else {
        $followers = array();
        $followers[] = $user_id;
    }

    do_action( 'pwuf_pre_follow_user', $user_id, $user_to_follow );

    // update the IDs that this user is following
    $followed = update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_following', $following );

    // update the IDs that follow $user_id
    $followers = update_user_meta( $user_to_follow, '_pwuf_followers', $followers );

    // increase the followers count
    $followed_count = pwuf_increase_followed_by_count( $user_to_follow ) ;

    if ( $followed ) {

        do_action( 'pwuf_post_follow_user', $user_id, $user_to_follow );

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and here to check if a user is following another:

```
function pwuf_is_following( $user_id, $followed_user ) {

    $following = pwuf_get_following( $user_id );

    $ret = false; // is not following by default

    if ( is_array( $following ) && in_array( $followed_user, $following ) ) {
        $ret = true; // is following
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

I tried to add this code after updating the user meta but nothing happen!

```
   $subscribers = explode(",", $user_to_follow );
    $emails      = array ();

    foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber ) {
        $user_info = get_userdata($subscriber);
        $emails[] = $user_info ->user_email;
    }
    $body = sprintf( $user_to_follow->display_name, 'followed your work! See <%s>' );

    wp_mail( $emails, 'New followers!', $body );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to send user an email when ever user is been followed by another user. Given this scenario, there is this action hook available in the plugin which is executed when following process is successful:

```
do_action( 'pwuf_post_follow_user', $user_id, $user_to_follow );
```

You can hook your own code to this action

```
add_action('pwuf_post_follow_user', $user_id, $user_to_follow) {

   $follower = get_userdata($user_id);
   $recipient = get_userdata($user_to_follow);
   $recipient_email = $recipient->user_email;
   $body = sprintf('%s followed your work!', $follower->display_name );
   wp_mail( $recipient_email , 'New follower!', $body );

}
```

Refernece: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: Can you please tell how can i get the profile url of the follower, so the user can rich the followers profile? i mean the followers name going to be href link!

Comment: @AdhamMohamed check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata for info you can retrieve

Comment: Thanks again @Ghazanfar i did it `$follower = get_userdata($user_id);
        $follower_url = get_author_posts_url( $user_id );
    $recipient = get_userdata($user_to_follow);
    $recipient_email = $recipient->user_email;
    $body = sprintf('%s followed your work!'. "\n\n", $follower->display_name );
    $body .= sprintf( 'Visit Artist Page: %s', $follower_url );
    wp_mail( $recipient_email , 'New follower!', $body );`